# Реализация переключения языков на сайте

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

На сайте реализуем функцию переключения языков. К сделать чтобы из ссылки, например, /site.com/**ru**/index.html мы переключались на /site.com/**en**/index.html ? 
Никак не могу понять логику вытягивания и подстановки. 
Сейчас код такой:

```
$('.language-select li').click(function(){
        var setLang = $('.language-select').data('location'),
            dataLangSelect = $(this).data('lang');
        $('.language-select').data('location', dataLangSelect);
        $('.language-select li').removeClass('active');
        $(this).toggleClass('active');
        if($(this).hasClass('active')){
            if(dataLangSelect == 'ua') {
                window.location = '/ua/';
            }
            if(dataLangSelect == 'ru') {
                window.location = '/ru/';
            }
            if(dataLangSelect == 'en') {
                window.location = '/en/';
            }
        }
    })
```

Comment: налету или с обновлением страницы?

Comment: Страница однозначно будет перезагружена.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот ответ:

```
$('.language-select li').click(function(){
        var setLang = $('.language-select').data('location'),
            dataLangSelect = $(this).data('lang');
        $('.language-select').data('location', dataLangSelect);
        $('.language-select li').removeClass('active');
        $(this).toggleClass('active');
        if($(this).hasClass('active')){
            var str = window.location.pathname,
                res = str.split("/");
                res[1] = dataLangSelect;
                var newLink = res.join('/');
            window.location = newLink;        
        }
    })
```